# Convert Xml document to C# Dictionary

Tags: c#, xml, dictionary, xmldocument, httpwebresponse

I make a request to a service and receive an xml response as shown below.  However, I'm trying to store the response values in a Dictionary (or store the values returned in variables) and I can't seem to make it work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

xml response received:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ncresponse NCERRORPLUS="!" BRAND="ABC" PM="CC" currency="GBP" amount="10" STATUS="9" ACCEPTANCE="test123" NCERROR="0" NCSTATUS="0" PAYID="39409494" orderID="92E5CE91">
</ncresponse>
```

c# code:

```
        try
        {
            // Write data
            using (Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                postStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
            }

            // Get response
            Dictionary<string, string> respValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            try
            {
                string body = String.Empty;

                using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
                {
                    // Get the response stream
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
                    body += reader.ReadToEnd();
                }

                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDoc.LoadXml(body);

                XmlNodeList list = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("ncresponse");
                string xmlResponse = list[0].InnerText;
            }
            catch (WebException wex)
            {
                throw;
            }
```

Comment: Where in your code are you trying to store the values in the dictionary?

Comment: That's a lot of boilerplate for a request. Have you considered friendly timesavers like `XElement` and `WebClient.UploadString()`?

Comment: just FYI... XDocument has a Load overload that accepts a stream https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838349(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi First I thought I'd try to store a returned value in a variable but xmlResponse returns nothing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;  // required namespace for linq-to-xml
/* ... get xml into 'body' string */
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(body);
```

to load the XML file into an `XDocument` object.

Then, you can use Linq-to-XML to parse the XML and `ToDictionary` extension method to create a key / value pair for each attribue of the XML:

```
 var output = doc.Element("ncresponse")
                 .Attributes()          
                 .Select(c => new {
                     Key = c.Name,
                     Value = c.Value
                  })
                 .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value);
```

It seems I overcomplicated things (credit goes to @KyleW). This:

```
 var output = doc.Element("ncresponse")
                 .Attributes()          
                 .ToDictionary(k => k.Name, v => v.Value);
```

is equivalent to the inital linq query. `Select` is only necessary only in case some pre-processing of the values placed in the dictionary is required.

**Ouput:**

```
[0] = {[NCERRORPLUS, !]}
[1] = {[BRAND, ABC]}
[2] = {[PM, CC]}
... etc
```

Comment: @Giorgos There is no xml file as such. It's returned as part of the StreamReader so what would the XDocument.Load(@"???");

Comment: @Bhav If you can place the XML into a string, then you can simply use `XDocument.Parse(yourString)`. `XDocument.Load` is used to load the xml file from file system.

Answer (score 3):

I needed to solve a similar problem, but my issue was a bit more complicated. The XML document could have any number of child collections, and collections within collections. Each node was guaranteed to have a unique name. I used the following code to place it into a dictionary. A recursive function is used to parse each XElement into the dictionary, or parse any child elements it might have.

```
    private static void RecParseXDoc(XElement element, Dictionary<string, string> xDict)
    {
        if (element.HasElements)
        {
            foreach (var childElement in element.Elements())
            {
                RecParseXDoc(childElement, xDict);
            }

        }

        xDict.Add(element.Name.ToString(), element.Value);
    }
```

We can then initiate the parse like so:

```
        var outputDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (var element in xDoc.Root.Elements())
        {
            RecParseXDoc(element, outputDict);
        }
```

If your XML might have duplicate node names, you can do a .TryGetValue prior to adding the element to the dictionary.

I'm leaving this answer here on the chance others with the issue of child elements finds your question.